# Convergent sequence has finitely many nonzero terms

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, topological-vector-spaces

I am working on the following exercise:

Show that a sequence $$(a_1, 0, 0, \ldots), (0, a_2, 0, \ldots), \ldots, (0, \ldots, 0, a_n, 0, \ldots), \ldots$$ in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ has a limit if and only if it has only finitely many nonzero terms.

I don't think this is correct. Take $a_i = \frac{1}{i}$. Clearly this sequence converges to 0 but there are not finitely many nonzero terms. Am I missing something here?

Comment: What topology are you using on $\mathbb{R}^\infty$?

Comment: Direct limit topology. Sorry.

Comment: "Clearly this sequence converges to 0" -- why is this clear? You would need to actually prove this to contradict the claim (in fact the sequence does not converge to 0 in the direct limit topology).

Comment: @diracdeltafunk - I understand limits of sequences in terms of metrics, i.e. a sequence converges to some point if the "distance" per the metric goes to 0. But it seems like we're not necessarily given a metric here. What does it mean for a sequence to converge to 0 for a general topology? Would it be that the point is a limit point of the sequence taken as a set?

Comment: Aha, you've identified the source of the problem! This exercise was tricky for you because you don't yet know the definition of the main concept being discussed (convergence of sequences in a topological space).

Comment: In general, it is almost impossible to prove that some object (e.g. this sequence in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$) has a certain given property (e.g. "is/is not convergent") if you don't know how both the object and the property are defined! So this should *always* be your first step when thinking about a math exercise -- "do I fully understand the definitions of every object and property appearing in this exercise?". If not, you need to backtrack and take the time to learn and understand those definitions.

Comment: I imagine this exercise comes from a course you're taking, or a book you're reading. In that case, the definition of convergence in a topological space must have been presented prior to this exercise. You should really go back through your notes/book to try to find it, for your own sake -- there is very likely other important info nearby that you've also forgotten or not absorbed well.